# how to make use of prototypal inheritance in js

Tags: javascript

I'm getting stuck because of less understanding of prototypal inheritance. I want to know what is prototypal inheritance exactly and how it is implemented.

Could you please show one ease example?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/   http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/

Comment: read [Douglas "grandmastmaster of JS" Crockford's Article](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) or a talk from [Brendan "the father" Eich](http://www.aminutewithbrendan.com/pages/20110216)

Comment: Imagine you have an object and you want to look up a property. Now imagine the property doesn't exist. What if you could make it automatically continue the search for that property on a different object? That's basically what prototypal inheritance is.

Comment: This should not have votes to close as "too broad". If it's a duplicate, that's one thing, but good crisp entry-level explanations are hard to find, and this is one of the important things SO can do (if we let it).

Comment: The OP asked - "could you please show one ease example?". I think that is what I have done.

Answer (score 1):

### *At its core*

Imagine you have an object and you want to look up a property. Now imagine the property doesn't exist. What if you could make it automatically continue the search for that property on a different object? That's basically what prototypal inheritance is.

---

### *How do we do it?*

So then the only question is how to create this relationship between objects. Well, that's the weird part.

I'll start with the main, historical way of doing it. That is using functions.

First thing to note is that a function in JavaScript is itself an object. It can have its own properties, and it uses prototypal inheritance to gain access to other properties.

So let's start by creating a function.

```
function Foo() {
    // our function
}
```

So now we have a function named `Foo`. Our new function automatically gets a property named `prototype` when it's created. That property references an (almost) empty object.

```
console.log(typeof Foo.prototype); // object
```

Why does that property and object exist? Well, they exist to support the weird way that JavaScript has formed that relationship between objects that I described above.

Basically, the `Foo.prototype` object is what we're going to use as the "backup" object when looking for new properties on our objects. But we still haven't formed any special relationship between the object we want to use, and the `Foo.prototype` object.

---

### *Putting it to work*

To do that, we actually invoke the function using the `new` operator.

```
var my_object = new Foo();
```

And there we go. So now `my_object` is a new, empty object. But it has in its "prototype chain" that object that is dangling from our `Foo` function off of its `.prototype` property. In other words, when we look for a property on `my_object`, if the property doesn't exist, it'll continue the search on the `Foo.prototype` object.

---

### *See it in action*

Trouble is that we haven't added anything that we might find useful to `Foo.prototype`. But there actually is one property on that object. That property was also automatically created when we made our `Foo` function, and it's the `.constructor` property.

What does that property reference? It has a reference back to the `Foo` function. In other words:

```
Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo; // true
```

Alright, so if our `my_object` is empty, and if when looking for a property on `my_object` that doesn't exist, it continues the search on the `Foo.prototype` object, then that should mean that we should be able to automatically get to the `Foo.prototype.constructor` property from `my_object`.

```
my_object.constructor === Foo; // true
```

And it works. Since `my_object` didn't have a property named `constructor`, it continued its search on the object from which it inherits, which is `Foo.prototype`, which as we know, has a `.constructor` property that refers to the `Foo` function.

---

### *Customizing for our code*

Super. But how do we set up other properties that are more useful to us in our code? We just add them to `Foo.prototype`. That will let our `my_object` find those properties if the object doesn't own them directly.

```
// give a custom property to `Foo.prototype`
Foo.prototype.bar = "foobar";

// see if we can access that property on your object
my_object.bar === "foobar"; // true
```

Sure enough, it worked. So let's see if we can create a new object from `Foo` that also has access to that `.bar` property.

```
var another_object = new Foo();

another_object.bar === "foobar"; // true
```

Again, it works. This is because all objects created by invoking `Foo` using the `new` keyword will have in their prototype chain the `Foo.prototype` object. In other words, `Foo.prototype` is *shared* among all instances created from `Foo`.

So if we now modify the `Foo.prototype.bar` property, it will be reflected in both objects we created.

```
Foo.prototype.bar = "raboof";

my_object.bar === "raboof";      // true
another_object.bar === "raboof"; // true
```

So we can see that both of our objects are simply looking for properties that they don't have by passing the search on to the next object in their "prototype chain", which is that weird object dangling off the `Foo` function... `Foo.prototype`.

---

### *There's more to learn*

There are newer ways to set up this object relationship, but this is the original way, and in spite of its weirdness, should probably be understood first.

Comment: Thanks for giving me useful information.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand it:

This could be considered a constructor

```
var Thing = function(){
    this.method1 = function(){
        alert( "method 1" );
    }
}
```

This is an instance of it

```
var a_thing = new Thing();

a_thing.method1();
```

Now, if you add something to the prototype of the constructor, it is automatically available to the already instantiated object.

```
Thing.prototype.method2 = function(){
    alert( "method2" );
}

a_thing.method2();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @dhirendra - can you accept it as the answer or vote me up please? (rep whoring)

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest example I can think of,
pizza class inherits from circle by using this line:

```
pizza.prototype = new circle();
```

Full example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        // base class
        function circle(radius){
            this.radius = radius;

            this.getArea = function ()
            {
                return (this.radius * this.radius) * Math.PI;
            };

            this.foo = function ()
            {
                return "circle foo";
            };

            return true;
        }

        // child class
        function pizza(flavour, radius){
            circle.call(this, radius);
            this.flavour = flavour;

            this.foo = function ()
            {
                return "pizza foo";
            };
            return true;
        }

        // Inheritance
        pizza.prototype = new circle();

        function Go(){
            // Instancing new object
            var myCircle = new circle(8);
            var myPizza = new pizza("Onion", 5);

            // Calling property
            var pizza_area = myPizza.getArea();

            // Calling override foo function
            var foo = myPizza.foo();

            // Calling foo base class
            var base = pizza.prototype.foo.call(myPizza);
            //Line.prototype.someFunction.call(myLine);

            var isBase = myCircle instanceof pizza;
            isBase = myPizza instanceof pizza;
        }

    </script>    
</head>
<body onload="Go();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. This is overcomplicated and uses some bad practises. It definitely is not the simplest one.

Comment: @Bergi can you elaborate about the bad practice?

Comment: You're creating lots of methods in the constructors which better would be on the prototype - the key feature the OP had asked for actually. And your `pizza.prototype` is a circle instance without a radius - you [should not use `new` there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572).